# WolframAlpha API high resolution images

Tags: ios, wolframalpha

I'm using the WolframAlpha API and try to download the images that are provided when setting `format=plaintext,image` in the URL query. However I realized that these images had a resolution that is only half of the resolution of the images that are provided from the WolframAlpha application from the AppStore. I wonder how I could get these images as well, yet it would be understandable if it wasn't possible.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the **mag** parameter:

> The mag parameter controls the magnification of pod images. (...) Let's say your program will be displaying its results on a very high-density screen like a tablet, with a screen density of 240 pixels per inch and a screen width of 960 pixels (4 inches). If you specify width=900, you will get images that fit the screen, but fonts will be tiny---the images will look shrunken by the high number of pixels per inch. If you specify, say, mag=2, then your images will still be wrapped to fit the 900 pixel screen, but they will be blown up by a factor of 2 and therefore much more readable

To get the scale factor of main screen you do `let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale` and use it as the mag paramenter.

And don´t forget, after downloading the image and creating a new instance of `UIImage`, explicitly set its scale. Supposing you receive the image as a `NSData`, you could do:

```
let image = UIImage(data, scale: scale)
```

For more information, check the section *Controlling the Width of Results* from [WolframAlpha API Documentation](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/documentation.html)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've been looking for it for more than a week now and I  haven't seen it in the documentation either.